# My renedered image is completely blacked out

Tags: rendering

When I try to render my scene, everything blacks out. Another weird thing is even if I set the scene camera to active 'Camera', it just switches to 'Plane' when I press numpad 0.
Just to save your time, I have tried all of the following 6 solutions, and none of them were the case.

https://gachokistudios.com/why-a-blender-render-result-is-completely-blank-or-black-and-how-to-fix-it/

You can download my .blend file from the following link. No textures have been used, so you should be able to open it just as it is. I would very much appreciate your help. Thank you so much in advance.

https://file.io/09hpX1ExkP0m

Comment: Hi :). Please upload your file at https://pasteall.org/blend/, the linked file was deleted ;)

Comment: I'm sorry the file wasn't avialable anymore. The problem was solved after a bit, but I still appreciate your trouble and time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes through an accidentally pressed shortcut (*Ctrl + Num0*), you can set a (non-camera) object as the *active camera* (causing that object to be selected when using the camera shortcut - Num0). If this happens, select your camera in the outliner, and make it the active camera again:

[image: Camera]

Comment: Thank you so much! I guess it's those small things that can get you stucked sometimes. Learned a great lesson.

Comment: Yeah - It happened to me back when I was first learning blender... I thought I was losing my mind